# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for #<Guestbook:0x007fd39b7f0f50>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods, each

I am getting the above error in my app that I was not getting before. That is the output from the logs.

My controller looks like;

```
def index
        @guestbook = Guestbook.all
    end

    def new
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new
        @guestbooks = Guestbook.all.limit(1).page(params[:page])
    end

    def create
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new(guestbook_params)

        if @guestbook.save
            flash.now[:notice] = "Thanks for taking the time to write us! We greatly appreciate it!"
            render :new
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = "Your message failed to post, please try again"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def guestbook_params
        params.require(:guestbook).permit(:name, :email, :message)
    end
```

My view looks like;

```
<div class="span1">
    <% @guestbook.each do |g| %>
        <br/>
        <h4><%= g.name %>, <%= g.created_at %><br/></h4>
        <%= g.message %><br/>
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And my model is titled Guestbook.rb with no associations.

I run the rails console to see my database, I get the data, so the form submission is working, but when I try to render the data it is getting an undefined error for nil:class.

I looked at the other answers on here, but could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: Your `@guestbook` appears to be an instance, not a relation. `each` is used to loop over a relation. What view is this? New or index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your index method to use the plural for the instance variable which will be clearer.

```
def index
  @guestbooks = Guestbook.all
end
```

And use the plural in the view

```
<div class="span1">
  <% @guestbooks.each do |g| %>
    <br/>
    <h4><%= g.name %>, <%= g.created_at %><br/></h4>
    <%= g.message %><br/>
    <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

finally, since the `create` action will always display the `new` template (and since you seem to show a list of guestbooks in the `new` template) you should ensure that you build the collection in the `create` action as well.

```
def create
  @guestbook = Guestbook.new(guestbook_params)
  @guestbooks = Guestbook.all.limit(1).page(params[:page])
  ...
```